# Can inherit Math object into es6 class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Can I extend `Math` object in my class? I want `Math` static field to be static inside my class.

```js
class MyClass extends Math {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

console.log(MyClass.PI);
```

Comment: `Math` is an object, not a class, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

Comment: Math mostly has static methods and properties. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @adiga according to mdn, all its methods (and properties) are static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you could use a `function` instead of a `class` and use `setPrototypeOf`:

```js
function MyClass() {
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(MyClass, Math);
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(Math);

console.log(MyClass.PI);
```

But `Math` can't be instantiated. Using it like a class doesn't make much sense. It would probably make more sense to use just a plain object which inherits from Math:

```js
const MyObj = Object.create(Math);
MyObj.someOperation = () => {
  console.log('some operation');
};

console.log(MyObj.PI);
MyObj.someOperation();
```